# Let the user choose from a range of numbers in preference screen

Tags: android, android-preferences

I would like the user to be able to enter/pick a number in between 300 and 2000. I tought of useing EditTextPreference but then I wouldn't know how to check if the value is actually in range. i'm very new to preference screens.

My Preferences.java

```
public class Preferences extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.simple);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment, "SETTINGS_FRAGMENT");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }


    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment{

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_layout);
        }
    }


}
```

And the pref_layout.xml (it will only contain one preference)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="General">

        <EditTextPreference
            android:title="frequency"
            android:summary="frequency"
            android:key="interval"
            android:defaultValue="300"
            android:numeric="integer"/>


    </PreferenceCategory>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is instead of extending a `PreferenceFragment`, what you can do is extend a `EditTextPreference`. And you can override `showDialog()` and in `showDialog()` you can add a  `TextWatcher`. Your code should look something like this.

```
public static class InputValueEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {

    public SettingsFragment(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
        super.showDialog(state);

        EditText et = getEditText();
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Dialog d = getDialog();
                int num = Integer.parseInt(s.getText().toString());
                if (d instanceof AlertDialog) {
                    AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) d;
                    Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                    // Check the EditText value
                    if (num >= 300 && num <= 2000) {
                        // Enable OK button
                        positiveButton.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        // Disable the button.
                        positiveButton.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And now in the xml file it should be

```
<PreferenceScreen
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

<<package name>.InputValueEditTextPreference
    android:title="@string/pref_input_value_label"
    android:key="@string/pref_input_value_key"
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_input_value_default"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

What this does is it disables the ok Button based on the value inserted into the edit text.

Now the value which is entered by the user is saved into `SharedPrefrence` which can be acssed by the key which you have given to the EditText.

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand where to place this code, and I don't know what attrubuteSet is. I just copied your class and replaced my _SettingsFragment_ class. I guess I sould make some modifications to _Preferences_ class too?

Comment: @drogaleggera the only thing you have to do after implementing this class is. You have to use the new class in the place of `EditTextPrefernce` in your xml. I have also modified my answer with detailed explanation. For any query feel free to ask.

Comment: I got it working, never heard of using custom classes in xml. Thank you again.

Comment: @drogaleggera please mark this as answer since it solves your problem

Comment: That's a lot of work to do something that I cant' believe isn't built-in.